# How to split local changes from main project and subtree libraries

Tags: git, subtree

In my project I have 3 subdirectory with library projects merged by subtree strategy. Suppose I *checkout master* branch and make changes in main project as well as in libraries files. I can't checkout any lib branch because I will lose local changes. Run **stash** in one branch and **apply** it in another is not good idea.

How to split changes and commit it in right branches using only standard git tools (without any git-subtree packages)???

Comment: It looks like what you are doing is not what is foreseen with the git workflow. You have different branches checked out at the same time in the same working directory? Don't do such things. At least, use separate working directories (there is `git-new-workdir` for this).

Comment: As far as read in Pro Git book it is common workflow for subtree. My main project branch (master) tracks their and subdirectories files. I have separate branches for each project and master branch to witch library projects merge. Please correct me if I misunderstood subtree strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different working directories. ie:

```
git clone x main_project
git clone x lib1
git clone x lib2
```

A better way would be to use git-new-workdir script that's in git/conrib as Paulo Ebermann above has pointed out. You can find more information on how to use it over here: http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir.html